# Cannot get results for Solr queries starting with stop words

Tags: json, search, solr, lucene

I am trying to configure the platform allowing queries that start with a stop word. 
I have the following document:

```
        {
          "responseHeader":{
            "status":0,
            "QTime":1,
            "params":{
              "indent":"true",
              "q":"*:*",
              "wt":"json"}},
          "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "weight_metric":0.3,
                "maximumPowerDraw":9,
                "beamAngle":50,
                "name_de":"German",
                "type":["product"],
                "id":"5dac69a9-7d54-43f9-b815-0a54e519a1f0",
                "name":"Aloa something"
                }]
          }}
```

With a field called name, one for English (Default) and another called name_de for German.
But I cannot understand why I do this query http://localhost:8080/solr-webapp/collection1/select?q=name_de:German%20welcher&wt=json&indent=true I am able to see  the document in the results.
While  if  I do this other query with a stop word (welcher) at the beginning I cannot get any result http://localhost:8080/solr-webapp/collection1/select?q=name_de:welcher%20German%20welcher&wt=json&indent=true

While I would like to have the same result of  the first query in both cases.
 However, for the default language it works fine.
Here I copy some snippets of my schema.xml

```
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
                 <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
                   add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
                     <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
                     <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
-->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- German -->
    <fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
        <!--<filter class="solr.GermanMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>-->

      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

...

    <field name="name" type="text_en" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="name_de" type="text_de" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
...

    <copyField source="*_de" dest="text_de"/>
    <copyField source="name" dest="text"/>

...

<field name="text" type="text_general" stored="false" indexed="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
<field name="text_de" type="text_de" stored="false" indexed="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this unwanted behavior?
(btw for the field name instead I have the expected behavior with the result http://localhost:8080/solr-webapp/collection1/select?q=name:the%20Aloa&wt=json&indent=true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your query syntax.  See this example in the [Lucene query syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields).  your query is:

```
name_de:welcher German welcher
```

Only the first query term is going to be searched in name_de.  The rest will be searched in the default field (name).  You're query is effectively:

```
name_de:welcher name:German name:welcher
```

Instead, try:

```
name_de:(welcher German welcher)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply femtoRgon, do you know also if I can embed the language somewhere else in the query? ie I have the field name in French (name_fr) and German (name_de) and instead of specify always the language in the field name (name_de:something) I would like to have a query like q=name:something&language=de. is it possible? and eventually is having a query like name_de:something a good practice?

Comment: You are definitely doing the right thing by indexing different languages separately. One alternative would be to index different languages in entirely separate documents, and have a language code *field*. I don't really see anything wrong with what you are doing though.